# How can I add a title in the toolbar of plugin InAppBrowser(Ionic 3)?

Tags: typescript, webview, ionic3, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am using the InAppBrowser plugin of ionic-native.

The code is below:

```
const ref = this.inAppBrowser.create(encodedURL, ‘_self’, location=yes,toolbar=yes,toolbarcolor=${primaryColor},closebuttoncolor=#ffffff,hidenavigationbuttons=yes,hideurlbar=yes);
```

As you can see, I am showing the toolbar of the InAppBrowser. The toolbar has a color that I give via a var and contains the close button.

I want also to add a text title in the middle with white color instead of showing the url.

How can I achieve this? I tried `executeScript` function but it does not work..

```
this.ref.addEventListener('loadstop', () => {
      alert(`primary color is : ${primaryColor}`);
      this.ref.executeScript(
        {
          code:
            "const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = 'TITLE WORKS';
      document.head.appendChild(div);
      const style = document.createElement('style');
      style.type = 'text/css';
      style.innerHTML = '.cssClass { color: #ffff00; }';
      div.classList.add('cssClass');
      document.body.appendChild(div);"
        },
        () => {
          alert('Image Element Successfully Hijacked');
        }
      );
      this.ref.insertCSS(
        {
          code: 'header { background: #ffff00'
        },
        () => {
          alert('stop');
        }
      );
    });
```

Comment: There is no direct that is provided by inappbrowser docs, but maybe if you can inspect the inappbrowser and get the toolbar name by its class and append text to the inner html of toolbar.

Comment: @MostafaHarb hi. Thanks for the answer. I tried this but i cannot find it in the inspect.

Comment: Try if you can get the whole document html of the in app browser and you can analyze the code part by part after the event of page loaded get emited